# Python/Pandas, having trouble with dictionaries, and excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am new to Python and am having a few issues with a practice program.What I am trying to do is convert two csv to list, add the two list together to make one dictionary, remove duplicates and then convert to an excel sheet.

I am stuck at add the two lists together in the way I would like (and the remove duplicates but that can wait). Here is my current code and output.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open("football.csv","rt") as f1, open("fb_abrev.csv", "rt") as f2:
    #Convert lines of CSV to LIST
    football = list(csv.reader(f1))
    abrev = list(csv.reader(f2))

#Define Function
def Dictionary_List(football, abrev):
    for ab in abrev:
        if ab not in football:
             football.append(ab)
    return football

 #Print and call function
 print(Dictionary_List(football, abrev))

 df = pd.DataFrame(football)
 df.to_excel('output.xlsx', header = False, index = False)
```

My output looks like this:

[Output I Get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqQnv.png)

But I would like the output to resemble this:

[Output I Need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bIa8.png)

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please format your current output and the expected output as text in the question, instead of screenshot images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to use merge to combine both DataFrames(you need to convert instead of list, to DataFrame) in one by the index and then converting the final DataFrame into a excel file, like this:

```
d = pd.merge(football, abrev, how="inner", left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

And then converting the DataFrame "d" to excell file.

Comment: Thank you! That was a far easier approach.